# jquery drag and drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have the following...

```
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

I need to drag each item from one `ul` to another, but avoid duplications in the same `ul` and just add the item to the dropped ul.

using jQuery i have tried many things but there is always something that messes it up.

any ideas ? thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the jqueryui
http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

makes it very easy to dragdrop/resize/drop...

Comment: sortables work nicely but the problem is everytime i drop something there are duplicated items

Answer (score 0):

This is complicated because you have multiple sortables and it's tricky to get working. I have done it using the sortable controller with the connectTo option specifying the other possible targets.

Comment: I am confortable using sortables but the only problem is that I only need a copy of that item. so if the item already exists i could display an error or disregard the dragging

Comment: I haven't done this in a while, so my memory is a bit hazy, but I think you can hook the 'receive' or 'drop' event on the target, do some validation, and return false to reject the draggable.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove duplications before add

```
$( "li" ).draggable({
 appendTo: "ul",
 helper: "clone"
});
$( "ul" ).droppable({
 activeClass: "ui-state-default",
 hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
 accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
 drop: function( event, ui ) {
  $( this ).find( "li:contains('" + ui.draggable.text()  + "')" ).remove();

  $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
 }
})
```